# Regex to match either: 1)whole number, 2) number with fraction with only 2 digits after decimal or 3) fraction with only 2 digits after decimal

Tags: html, regex

I'm not too familiar with Regex and I need some client side validation for number input.

It should match either of

1. Whole number
2. Number with fraction with only 2 digits after decimal
3. Fraction with only 2 digits after decimal

I intend to put this in the "Pattern" attribute. I've tried:

```
^\d{0,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

but it is still allowing 1 digit after decimal point.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, I tried this: "^\d{0,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$"

Comment: Code I tried is still allowing 1 digit after decimal point.

Comment: Pattern attribute of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your existing regex:

```
 "^\d{0,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$"
```

The `\d{1,2}` specifically says allow a 1 *or* 2 numeric digits. If you want to strictly specify two numeric digits, then do

```
"^\d{0,6}(\.\d{2})?$"
```

or

```
"^\d{0,6}(\.\d\d)?$"
```

Answer (score 0):

the regex

> ^\d{0,6}(.\d{2})?$

can match with nothingness; i.e.: empty input matches

You could use:

> ^\d{1,6}(.\d{2})?$|^.\d{2}$

instead.

http://regexr.com/3chv2